# How to move a child components content to its parent - Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I would like to shift the contents of a child component to it's parent component. I've tried doing this using "defineSlots" but I can't figure out how to do it. I keep getting " Converting circular structure to JSON" when trying to get the child element from the slot.

E.g

```
<Parent>
    <!-- Move the "p" element here -->
    <Child>
        <p class="m-0">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </Child>
</Parent>
```

**Attempt**

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import {defineSlots} from "vue";

const slots = defineSlots<{
  default(): any
}>()

</script>

<template>
  // Get the first childs content
  {{ slots.default()[0].default() }}
</template>

<style scoped lang="sass">

</style>
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: $setup.slots.default(...)[0].default is not a function
```

How this can be achieved with Vue 3 composition API?

Comment: Why do you need to move that content ?

Comment: You should actually show your attempt at using defineSlots that leads to the error so we can tell what it is you're doing wrong.  It's also not clear what your goal is.  Should the `<p>` element appear literally outside and above the Child element (what your code snippet implies)?  Or should `<p>` be inside the Child but inner content provided by the parent (via props or slots)?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I would like to implement something similar to PrimeVues TabView component. https://primevue.org/tabview/

Comment: Process vnodes from a slot. You can do this in a more flexible way in render function, but this may work for a template too. Since you refer primevue, you can actually check how it does this, it's the way it's usually done in vue https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/master/components/lib/tabview/TabView.vue#L349 . Since Child isn't rendered, there's no instance to have a slot, there's only vnode.children